# finding whether an exe is dynamically linked (windows)

Tags: windows

How to find whether an exe is dynamically linked or statically linked in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Windows apps are dynamically linked to the Windows API. If you need to determine how a specific non-Windows library (like libxml or somesuch) was linked, Visual Studio includes a program called DEPENDS.EXE that will show all the DLL's an exe is linked against. If the library in question isn't listed, then it's either linked statically, or it's not linked at all.

Answer (score 2):

Static/dynamic linking is a transitive property. You have to specify to what it is statically/dynamically linked. And everything is dynamically linked to the winapi.